# SSLPeerUnverifiedException for HTTPS requests if Parse pushes initialized

Tags: android, ssl, parse-platform, android-volley

I've started getting the following Volley error right after adding Push functionality through Parse.com:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Cannot verify hostname: xxxxx.yy
```

xxxxx.yy is the host that I'm communicating with using HTTPS. The way the connection is set up is quite usual. E.g. this is a caller function:

```
public static void login(final String token, final Activity activity) {
    String requestUrl = AppConstant.LOGIN;

    final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
        params.put("token", token);
    }
    params.put("useragent", AppConstant.USER_AGENT);
    params.put("version", getVersionName(activity));

    JsonFormRequest myRequest = new JsonFormRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            requestUrl,
            params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    ...
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    ...
                }
            }
    );

    MfApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(myRequest, "tag_login_phone");
}
```

It adds request to a queue:

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

The queue is created once in the following way:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

If I remove the following Parse initialization code from my Application class the error is gone:

```
Parse.initialize(this);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("general");
```

What's the reason of the issue and what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

For any other people with the exact same problem: updating the Android Parse SDK version to 1.13.1 solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a mismatch of url.
The request url that you are sending from android may use url like :
https://domain
but in your server url will be like 
http://domain
So there maybe no SSL in your website that's why exception is thrown.
Hope it helps